# Trying to center my text in my tab navigation. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: html, css

Heres my html for my tabbed navigation bar. Im having trouble centering the text within the li tags and putting padding on the top is not somthing I want to do because I want to put padding around all the text to make the whole tab clickable. If theres any advice for that as well please feel free to give me advice. So how can I make my link text centered and if possible how can I make the whole tab clickable?

```
<div id="tab_container">
                <nav id="tabs">
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Our Staff</a></li>
                        <li class="inactive"><a href="#">book</a></li>
                        <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                        <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

This is my CSS. Please tell where I went wrong?!

```
 #tab_container
{
background-color: #222;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
display: block;
position: relative;
max-width: 970px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#tabs 
{
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 970px;
background-color: #222;
padding-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

#nav 
{
width: 100%;
max-width: 970px;
text-align: center;
}

ul
{
float: left;
max-width: 970px;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
text-align: center;

}

ul li
{
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
    width: 158px;
height: 70px;
background-color: black;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

ul li a
{
color: #54544b;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;

}

a:hover
{ 
color: #CF7BA1;
}

.active a
{
text-decoration: underline;
color: #CF7BA1;

}
```

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome/IE10 - what browser is causing issues? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2Rc8/) btw.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exvSV/

Comment: Tested in Chrome and FireFox, looks same. Centering horizontal or vertical?

Comment: for now im just using it in chrome and then I will work with cross browser platforms. I just want to get the right look in chrome.

Comment: How about this as a base for your menu: http://jsfiddle.net/exvSV/1/

Comment: I need the text to be in the center of the li not centered in the middle on the top.

Comment: thx i will use that if i cant' find my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Really simple. Just add `line-height: 70px;` to your `a` tag.

So the css would be:

```
ul li a
{
color: #54544b;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;

line-height: 70px;

}
```

Where the 70px is the height of the list element.

**Option 2:**

Alternatively, you could set your A to `display: block;` and add padding to that. This would make it clickable, but personally, I prefer to use line height.

```
ul li a
{ 
display: block;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. It works thank you! I'm sure I'll have more questions to be answered!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Vertical centering is a pain in css.

Comment: I want to use the line height. I would also like to make each tab clickable. Is there a way to add padding to the links as well as line height and encompass the entire link to make it clickable?

Comment: Have a look at the second option in my answer. If you make the link block, you can add padding to it, and it will remain clickable.